# event.target.blur() not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a series of Bootstrap buttons like this:

```
<button :disabled="page === lastPage" type="button" class="btn btn-default" @click="getPage(lastPage)">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-forward"></span>
</button>
```

But the first line of the getPage method does not work:

```
event.target.blur();
```

Which is very strange, because I have another button in another component, on which event.taget.blur() works perfectly:

```
<button class="btn btn-default pull-right" @click="show()" type="button">Batch
    <span :class="{'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down': showForm, 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up': !showForm}"></span>
</button>
```

Does anyone know why this might be?

EDIT: I think it's when I click inside the SPAN that the blur doesn't work.

EDIT: oh well I solved it - I also need `event.target.parentNode.blur()` as well.

Comment: If you solved it, write an official answer and mark it as such.  It will give more clarity to those with similar issues and you'll score some points for it.  :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You likely want to use

```
event.currentTarget.blur()
```

That will always be the element you attached the event listener to where as `event.target` is the element the event originated from.

Comment: Simple answer and nice supplementary comment!

Answer (score 4):

I would consider using

```
if (document.activeElement != document.body) {
    document.activeElement.blur()
}
```

rather than navigating through nodes as it is less prone to error if the mark up changes.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, because the button contains a span, sometimes the user was clicking on the button itself, and sometimes on the span within. Hence, to reliably blur the button I needed:

```
event.target.blur();
event.target.parentNode.blur();
```

Comment: You likely want `event.currentTarget.blur()`, `currentTarget` is always the element with the listener added.

Comment: @BillCriswell even better. If you want, add this as the answer and I will accept.

Comment: Added the answer.

Comment: It works even two parents up `event.target.parentNode.parentNode.blur()`, nice!